# Flink session window scaling issues on YARN, Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, hadoop-yarn

**Job use case:**

Create groups of events (transactions) that relate to each other, based on event members and event-start-time, from 3 streams, not relying on processing time.
We have a input throughput of arround 20K events/sec.

All events of a transaction are sent to multiple kafka topics (job sources) on the end of a transaction, with the possibility of being late up to minutes.

We want to create event groups that have start times gaps less than a few seconds and are identified by a business key (e.g. country and transaction type).
Transactions can be seconds to hours long, but all events forming a group of transactions should arrive within ~5 minutes after the end of a transaction.

**Implementation:**

Job consumes 3 data sources, assigns timestamps & watermarks, maps events to a common interface, unions the streams, keys the unioned stream, creates a session window by transaction end time with a lateness, filters groups with huge numbers (bussiness reason), creates sub-groups (based on start-time) within the groups from the session window, and finaly sends the results to another topic.

**Issue:**

When running the job on a YARN cluster with kafka connectors as I/O, the job is slow, and not scaling well. (~3K events/sec on paralellism 1, to 5K events/sec on parallelism 10)

**What I tried:**

- Playing around with scaling TMs, slots and memory, at max we had arround 10TMs with 2 slot used, each with 32GB memory. (While maintaing the same paralelism on kafka partitions both on input and output)
- Playing arround with taskmanager.network.memory.fraction, containerized.heap-cutoff-ratio, taskmanager.memory.fraction
- Playing arround with kafka.producer.batch.size, kafka.producer.max.request.size
- Setting a fs and then a rocksdb backend and setting taskmanager.memory.off-heap to true, taskmanager.memory.preallocate to true
- Turning off checkpointing
- Upgrading Flink to 1.9.2, kafka-client to latest used, kafka servers, confluent and cloudera ...

**Code:**

I recreated a simplified use-case, the code is here: https://github.com/vladimirtomecko/flink-playground and the job looks basically like this:

```
implicit val (params, config) = PersonTransactionCorrelationConfig.parse(args)
val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.getConfig.setGlobalJobParameters(params)
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

val aTransactions: DataStream[PersonTransactionUniversal] =
  env
    .addSource(???)
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(???)
    .flatMap(_.toUniversal: Option[PersonTransactionUniversal])

val bTransactions: DataStream[PersonTransactionUniversal] =
  env
    .addSource(???)
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(???)
    .flatMap(_.toUniversal: Option[PersonTransactionUniversal])

val cTransactions: DataStream[PersonTransactionUniversal] =
  env
    .addSource(???)
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(???)
    .flatMap(_.toUniversal: Option[PersonTransactionUniversal])

aTransactions
  .union(bTransactions)
  .union(cTransactions)
  .keyBy(new PersonTransactionKeySelector)
  .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(config.gapEndSeconds)))
  .allowedLateness(Time.seconds(config.latenessSeconds))
  .aggregate(new PersonTransactionAggregateFunction)
  .filter(new PersonTransactionFilterFunction(config.groupMaxSize))
  .flatMap(new PersonTransactionFlatMapFunction(config.gapStartSeconds * 1000))
  .addSink(new DiscardingSink[PersonTransactionsGroup])


val backend = new RocksDBStateBackend(config.checkpointsDirectory, true)
backend.setPredefinedOptions(PredefinedOptions.SPINNING_DISK_OPTIMIZED)
env.setStateBackend(backend: StateBackend)

env.execute(getClass.getSimpleName)
```

**Question:**

- Is my implementation incorrect for this use case ?
- Is there something I have missed?
- Is there some other optimization I can try ?
- I have issues finding the bottleneck of this scenario, any tips there ?

Thank you

P.S. First time poster, be kind please.

**Edit 1:**

Input kafka topics are partitioned on the producer side with the same function used in the keyBy.

Partitions count is equal to or exactly 2 times greater than the parallelism of the flow.

Partitions per topic have a similar amount of events (deviation ~5-10%).

Topics are populated with different amounts of events (A has 10X more events than B, B has 1000X more events than C), but afaik this shouldnt be an issue.

Comment: Could you please add your key distribution? Data skew is very often the culprit of bad scaling behavior. In particular, if one key is disproportional often, you'd see a heavy utilization of one node while the others mostly idle.

Comment: The distribution of events between partitions on input topics which are created using the same keying function seems to be almost uniform with a deviation of ~ 5-10%